# What is the easiest way to search for user-defined columns in Intersystems Cache using SQL?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I am trying to search an extremely large Cache DB for columns that match a particular text string. In T-SQL, we could simply query the sys.columns view and then join it to sys.tables to get the name of all tables that have a column that matches the text we're looking for.

```
SELECT b.name AS table_name, a.name AS column_name
FROM sys.columns a
INNER JOIN sys.tables b ON a.object_id = b.object_id
WHERE b.type = 'U' AND a.name LIKE '%SEARCHTEXT%'
```

I've tried querying the `%DICTIONARY.COMPILEDPROPERTY`, but I haven't figured out how to limit the result set to user-defined classes. Is there a particular property that will limit the result set as desired? Perhaps a pattern on the class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT 
  parent AS class,
  parent->SqlQualifiedNameQ As table_name,
  name AS property
FROM %Dictionary.CompiledProperty 
WHERE NOT parent->id %STARTSWITH '%'
```

Executed in every namespace beyond `%SYS`/`SAMPLES`/`DOCBOOK` would return user defined tables (system tables start with `%`, users should not use table names starting with `%`)

Comment: This does the trick for the version of Cache I have access to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Caché do you have?

Starting with 2015.1 you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema

```
SELECT b.table_name AS table_name, a.column_name AS column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns a
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables b ON a.table_name = b.table_name
WHERE b.table_type <> 'SYSTEM TABLE' and a.column_name LIKE '%Age%'
```

Full list of tables in INFORMATION_SCHEMA is in Class Reference http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&PACKAGE=1&CLASSNAME=INFORMATION.SCHEMA

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which version it is, but I guess it's not 2015.1 since I get an error when I tried to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

`[SQLCODE: <-30>:<Table or view not found>]`

Comment: Run $zversion in terminal to find out the version number. Like this: USER> write $zversion

Comment: I don't have access to the terminal that I know of. I just have a user/pass with the reader permissions to connect to the server via ODBC. Is there a SQL-based equivalent?